# How can we save the syncfusion diagram as stream and load the stream from the database

Tags: syncfusion

I am using syncfusion diagram. In that diagram i want to load the stream from database and i want to save the stream to database. He has provided the sample project but that doesn't work for me. The link is

```
 http://www.syncfusion.com/support/forums/diagram-mvc/105418/How-to-display-sample-diagram-using-entities-model-in-aspnet-mvc3-razor-view.
```

Can anybody tell me what is the error and how can i rectify that.
Hope you will understand my question.

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any error messages when you try to run the sample provided by Syncfusion? If so, you can post them here or on the Syncfusion forums.

If you need the patch mentioned in the forum post, we have created a support incident under your account and the patch will be provided to you.

Comment: i am not getting error the stream is not saving. Can i change the dll to the new dll